# How to connect a file_field to the upload action in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I'm trying to add to a very simple data entry form, a button that allows the user to upload a file to the servers file system so that the url to that file can be placed in a field of the database.

So far, I've worked out that in the _form...erb file, I can add the file_field helper:

```
<%= form_for(@business) do |f| %>
<% if @business.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@business.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this business from being saved:</h2>

<ul>
<% @business.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :deletedFlag %><br />
<%= f.check_box :deletedFlag %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

...

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :logoURL %><br />
<%= f.text_field :logoURL %>

    <%= f.file_field :imagefile %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :streetAddress %><br />
<%= f.text_area :streetAddress %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This gives me a form with a "Choose file" button.  Clicking on that allows the selection of the file.  Great.

Now, from the ruby guide at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files I'm told to add something like:

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:business][:imagefile]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

to my controller.

What I haven't worked out is how that file_field gets connected to that 'upload' action.  I can see in the logs that the button press accepts the filename, etc, but there's no indication that the file upload is started or attempted.

I've read a number of references, and they all seem to say that you need these two things, but (for me) they don't connect the dots.  Yes I'm very new to Ruby/Rails, so I'm obviously missing something fundamental.

Comment: can you post your complete _form, model and controller file? It will make it easier to help you rather than guessing.

Comment: I've added the form almost entirely now.  Just left out some fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to setup a *route* so that Rails can pass the request from your form into your controller, then setting up your form to use that route:

```
# config/routes.rb
post '/upload' => 'mycontroller#upload'

# app/views/some_model/new.html.erb
<%= form_for something, url: upload_path do |f| %>
...
```

This is probably the least recommended way of handling a file upload on Rails, especially for a new user, though. You would be much better off setting up [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), or [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) instead.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Yes I looked at Paperclip, but it seems heavy when all I wanted was a simple way to upload a file to a directory.  I don't want to add more to the database backing the site if I can help it (and I go the impression that Paperclip uses the db), and I don't want to overcomplicate it for the client (or myself for that matter).  The route is the sort of thing I was looking for, but if this is a bad way to go, can you link me to some explanation?  If I have to I'll go with a plugin/gem to do this, but I really want keep it simple.

Comment: @PKCLsoft A database is not heavy. It's better to track files uploaded rather than to have them littering a folder without any references to them from a structured store.

Comment: OK, that's a fair comment.  There would be a reference, but not as well managed.  Thanks.  I'll mark this as the answer and get on with doing it right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to specify multipart in your form_for like this?

```
<%= form_for(@uploadfile, :html => {:multipart =>true}) do |f| %>
```

Check the generated form html code, do you see this?

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>
```

Comment: I don't think I need it. I'm using rails 3.2, and the guide I linked to stated that.

Comment: @PKCLsoft You do need to specify multipart if you want a browser to upload a file.

Comment: In the guide it says you must specify `multipart: true`

Comment: But not for ruby 3.1+:  'Since Rails 3.1, forms rendered using form_for have their encoding set to multipart/form-data automatically once a file_field is used inside the block. Previous versions required you to set this explicitly.'